# Cannot connect to websocket server app inside docker-compose

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, websocket

Created an app, with websocket server, which should return some answer. I could establish a ws connection to a ws server when app is not containerized in docker.

But when I containerize it in a docker, I could not establish the ws connection:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  myapp
    container_name: MyApp
    hostname: MyApp-host
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapp
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    ports:
      - "3003:3003"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_URLS : "https://+:3003"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp\Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:3003
EXPOSE 3003

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AppFolder/MyApp.csproj", "AppFolder/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AppFolder/MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AppFolder"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

My websocket server is listening on ws://127.0.0.1:3003.

I exposed port 3003 in Dockerfile and added it it docker-compose, but I'm receiving such answer when I'm trying to establish ws connection to app in docker container via postman:

[image]

May be I've missed something in docker settings?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Removed from Dockerfile
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:3003

And docker-compose setting is in old variant

environment:
ASPNETCORE_URLS : "https://+:3003"

But nothing changed, when I replaced connection to wss:

[after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSi9G.png)

Maybe it could be, because for some reason env variable did not changed in env container?

[Env variables screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76b1Y.png)

**UPDATE-1**

Pasted the first answer code below, but nothing changed, still could connect with app only without docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result:
The reason was, that I've used the HttpListener class on a localhost IP.
First of all I changed listen address of WebSocket Server

- from : http://127.0.0.1:3003/
- to   : http://*:3003/

AND added a string into a docker file, after default EXPOSE values:

USER ContainerAdministrator

After that I've been able to connect to port 56222, that you could establish in docker compose or it will be established by docker itslef(without docker compose):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MmNZ.png)

on ANY ip with that port.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to the HTTP endpoint `ws://localhost:3003`, but your server only listens to the HTTPS endpoints. Change server to listen to HTTP endpoints:

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS : "http://+:3003"
```

If you want to use secure WebSockets then keep your server settings but connect to `wss://localhost:3003`. You also can listen to both schemas:

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS : "http://+:3003;https://+:3004"
```

In that case, you can connect either to `ws://localhost:3003` or to `wss://localhost:3004` (don't forget to add port 3004 binding).

---

NOTE: You don't need to bake `ASPNETCORE_URLS` into your image and expose custom ports. Let the server use default ports (80 and 443) and allow users to bind them to any port on the host:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AppFolder/MyApp.csproj", "AppFolder/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AppFolder/MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AppFolder"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
 services:
  myapp
    container_name: MyApp
    hostname: MyApp-host
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapp
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    ports:
      - "3003:80"
      - "3004:443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp\Dockerfile`
```

Now you can connect to `ws://localhost:3003` or `wss://localhost:3004`

Comment: Removed the ASPNETCORE_URLS variable from dockerfile and changed connection to https in postman, but this did not helped. The same error, but now with https localhost:3003 url

Comment: @Glaz97 are you connecting to `ws://localhost:3003`? Also, are you able to connect when you running app without docker?

Comment: I'am able to connect to app, when it is out of docker compose or without docker. 'wss://localhost:3003'

Comment: Tried both variants in postman 'wss://localhost:3003' and 'ws://localhost:3003'. Nothing changed

Comment: @Glaz97 I updated answer - for wss you can keep current server settings. But screenshot of Postman error says you are using ws

Comment: Pasted your code, but this did not helped me, still can establish connection only out of docker.